# A counterpart of Karhunen theorem

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

According to the Karhunen theorem, if the correlation function of a process $X(t)$
can be represented as 
$$
R(t,s)= \int_{\Lambda} f(t, \lambda) \overline{f(s, \lambda)}d\nu(\lambda)
$$
then the process can be represented as 
$$
X(t)=\int_{\Lambda} f(t, \lambda)dZ(\lambda),
$$
where $Z$ is an orthogonal random measure. Are there any counterparts of this theorem which guarantee that the measure $Z$ will be an independently scattered measure, i.e. 
$Z(A)$ and  $Z(B)$ are independent for $A$ and $B$ with an empty intersection?

Thanks in advance.